# Heroku does not allow CORS access to apps even on its own domain

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, cors, nuxt.js

I've been bashing my head against the wall on this for a while.

I have a Nuxt app that makes a call to a service of mine, both hosted on heroku. Here is what I ended up adding (after abandoning `cors()` as I am suspicious on what it does or does not do)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

I can confirm in my browser that in fact my server sends this information via DevTools.

Still, I see the following error:

[image]

These are test campaigns so I don't care about my own privacy here.

What the heck? The server CLEARLY responds with correct CORS policy. My Nuxt apps refuse to communicate all of a sudden because of cors issues as they attempt to make some calls.

I have seen a lot of bugs in my day but I am so totally lost I'm posting here so any advice or insight would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're using chrome, some cors policy changes in newest version might be the problem

Comment: "The server CLEARLY responds with correct CORS policy." — The error message clearly indicates that it doesn't.

Comment: "after abandoning cors() as I am suspicious on what it does or does not do"  — It does everything you need, really easily, in a widely used and well tested package.

Comment: I know it sounds trivial, but where is this middleware located in tha code? before the route that you call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the server itself calling to ipstack had an error omitting the `?` param aka it was an oversight and had nothing to do with CORS :(

Answer (score 1):

do you just serve json? for me it looks like you only allow json?

Comment: This was actually the right answer. My other items were too restrictive but they all fell under CORS as an umbrella

Comment: glad to hear that :)